# Telerik Button's text is not showing

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a simple form consists of several text boxes and 3 buttons which all are Telerik buttons.

```
 .RadButton_Metro.rbSkinnedButton {
            height: 32px !important;
        }
    </style>

<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showNotification() {
            var notification = $find("<%=RadNotification1.ClientID %>");
            setTimeout(function () {
                notification.show();
            }, 0);
        }
        function redirect() {
            window.location = window.location;
        }
        function CheckIfShow(sender, args) {
            debugger;
            var summaryElem = document.getElementById("<%= ValidationSummary1.ClientID%>");
            var noErrors = summaryElem.style.display == "none";
            args.set_cancel(noErrors);
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="maindiv" style="min-width: 400px; padding: 0; width: 400px; margin: 0;">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" runat="server">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 100%; padding: 0;">
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height: 23px!important;">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>General</legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 35%;">
                                <span>Board Name : </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 64%;">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txt_Instituton_Branch_Name" runat="server" style="width: 230px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_branchname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_Instituton_Branch_Name" CssClass="errorClass"
                                    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please, enter Board Name!" Display="None">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 35%;">
                                <span>Email : </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 64%;">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txt_Email" runat="server" TextMode="Email" style="width: 230px !important;height: 22px;"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_email" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_Email" CssClass="errorClass"
                                    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please, enter email!" Display="None">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 35%;">
                                <span>Board-Admin UserName : </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 64%;">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txt_admin_username" runat="server" style="width: 230px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_board_admin_username" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_admin_username" CssClass="errorClass"
                                    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please, enter username!" Display="None">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 35%;">
                                <span>Board-Admin Password : </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 64%;">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txt_Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" style="width: 230px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_password" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_Password" CssClass="errorClass"
                                    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please, enter password!" Display="None">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Additional Info</legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 35%;">
                                <span>Address Line 1 : </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 64%;">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" placeholder="address" ID="txt_adress" style="width: 230px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_adress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_adress" CssClass="errorClass"
                                    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please, enter Board adress" Display="None">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                           <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 35%;">
                                <span>Phone/Mobile No : </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="width: 64%;">
                                <asp:TextBox class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" ID="txt_Mobile" runat="server" style="width: 230px !important" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_mobile" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_Mobile" CssClass="errorClass"
                                    Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please, enter Board adress" Display="None">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 70%; padding: 1% 1% 0 0.5% !important">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlEventLine" runat="server">
                                <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding: 0;">
                                    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Width="100%" UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClientClicked="showNotification">
                                        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbSave" />
                                    </telerik:RadButton>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-right: 0;">
                                    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="100%" OnClientClicked="redirect" AutoPostBack="false">
                                        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass=" rbCancel" />
                                    </telerik:RadButton>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-right: 0;">
                                    <telerik:RadButton ID="btn_View" runat="server" Text="View Board"
                                        Width="169%" AutoPostBack="false">
                                        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass=" rbSearch" />
                                    </telerik:RadButton>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    <!-- notification -->
    <telerik:RadNotification RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadNotification1" runat="server" Width="300" Animation="FlyIn"
        OnClientShowing="CheckIfShow" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadow="true"
        LoadContentOn="PageLoad" Title="Fix these"
        TitleIcon="warning" EnableAriaSupport="true" ShowSound="warning" AutoCloseDelay="7000">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"></asp:ValidationSummary>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </telerik:RadNotification>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

any of the button text is not showing.

[image]

and also please notice these two textboxes , Email and phoneNumber. These textboxes having textmode property email and phone respectively. But while rendering its showing its width 224px instead of 230px.

[image]

Here is my requirement,
1. How to display text of those buttons 
2. How to fix textboxes width issue.